# What is the difference between v-html and triple mustache?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any difference between

`<div>{{{ myHtml }}}</div>`

and

`<div v-html="myHtml" />`

The question could be the same for `v-text` and double mustache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about `{{{` it's deprecated syntax valid only for old Vue 1
Even if your are using Vue 1 it's better to use compatible markup.

Mustache syntax is just shortcut, more convenient to use.
(v-text is there for completeness, you may want eg pass attributes dynamically etc. and then v-text can be useful)

Comment: Ho I'm so disappointed ! It would be extremly convenient to me for the creation of a little plugin :( 
But well seen I was asking myself why I hadn't seen that before. Now it makes sense